# Nice paper of statistics about brownian motion.

Tags: statistics, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have recently started a course about brownian motion (I am in my last year of university). During this course I have to find a research paper about brownian motion, understand it at most I can, and then sumarize it.

I am very unexperienced in this field, so I don't know where to start to look. I love statistic, so I tried to found something with both brownian and stats. I visited arxviv, but I haven't found something yet. Do you have any reference of research paper (not too hard if possible) about bronwian motion (or a generalization) that you loved ? I am open to every new discovery.

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: There were a bunch of papers in the 80's that were relatively elementary yet instructive (imho), the subject being the _typical_ shape of a random walk, which apparently is not just a spherical blob. Try searching rudnick gaspardi

Comment: There's always [this](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/MATH3075/r/Einstein_1905.pdf)

Comment: Thank you both for these recommendations !

Comment: Have you tried using an academic search engine like Google Scholar?

Comment: No, I have never used it. I should try.

Comment: Though not a paper, the books by Liptser, Shiryaev may be nice companions for this. You can check the TOC and then look into the references, though obviously dated for some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the first answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/intuition-behind-why-steins-paradox-only-applies-in-dimensions-ge-3  for a profound relation between Stein's paradox in statistics  and transience of random walk (and Brownian motion) in dimensions three and higher.

the relevant reference is:

L. Brown (1971). Admissible estimators, recurrent diffusions, and insoluble boundary value problems. Ann. Math. Stat., vol. 42, no. 3, pp. 855–903.